# How to determine which `Foos` have no associated `Bars`

Tags: sql-server

I want to find all `Foos` that do not have any associated `Bars`.

Here's the query I'm using.  It's returning no records:

```
select * from foos f where f.id not in(select b.foo_id from bars b);
```

However, I know that the `foo` `with id = 1583` has no associated `Bars`, so there should be at least one result in my previous query.

Can somebody point out a mistake I am making?  Thanks.

Comment: There are `NULL` values in the `bars.foo_id` column.

Comment: @ypercube, That is the issue.  I added `where foo_id is not null` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably `bars` that have `NULL` in `foo_id`.

```
select 1 where 55 not in (select 1 union all select null)
```

The above query returns 0 rows.

The solution is to change the query to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` as follows:

```
select * from foos f where not exists(select * from bars b where b.foo_id = f.id)
```

Not only is this safer as you don't have to manually exclude `NULL`s from the subquery, but also this construct will generally [provide better performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join). So for the most part, I recommend getting into a habit of doing it this way instead of using `NOT IN`.